# Android LogCat device disconnected

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I'm struggling a bit with Logcat. The phone disconnects from LogCat with the message "Device Disconnected" every time I push a button changing intents in my program.

What can cause this? And Why? Could it be my code throwing a error disconnecting LogCat? Or is this a LogCat issue?

I'v tried to restart eclipse, and stop the adb.exe process with no luck.

```
 : E/(): Device disconnected
```

Answer (score 14):

There may be some sync problem in DDMS. Just restart the eclipse it will work fine.

Comment: Some problem, but what porblem is it? Restarting it all the time is boring.

Answer (score 3):

This is a real problem in Eclipse DDMS. If you run `adb logcat` at the same time that Eclipse shows "device disconnected" you will most likely still see logcat output (this is what happens in my case). Only real explanation I can see is that DDMS has a bug.

My solution? Switch to IntelliJ. It doesn't have the same problem, or any similar problems that Eclipse DDMS has connecting to devices which are recognized by adb.

Answer (score 1):

Here is commented a solution that works for me, **Clear Log**:

[LogCat Stops Running in Eclipse Needs Restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011816/logcat-stops-running-in-eclipse-needs-restart)

Comment: Unrelated. When that happens, it shows 1 line at a time, but the line is not "device disconnected".

Answer (score 1):

I `restarted` my `device`, `closed eclipse`, used a `command prompt` opened at `android-sdk/platform-tools` to run `adb kill-server`, `reopened eclipse`, and then used that same `command prompt` to run `adb logcat`.

My problem was then fixed, though I'm not sure which step fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Just Type This Command In **Terminal**

```
adb devices
```

u should see this log:

```
List of devices attached
adb server version (40) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
* daemon started successfully *
FA57NY900383    device
```

And Run Again, Your application starts to run on your device

Answer (score 0):

So I resolved the issue. I'm not sure what part did the trick, but I noticed javaw.exe was running on the computer even though eclipse was closed. So I forced closed this one, unfortunately I also re-installed my Jelly Bean ROM. So I'm not sure what exactly did the trick. I bet it was the phone though.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem where it kept saying "Device Disconnected" when I could clearly hit Debug and select my phone, but for some reason I was expecting the LogCat to already be going.

But it will not be going if the phone is locked (facepalm).. After unlocking it seems fine.

Hope this helps someone else that doesn't realize their phone is locked when trying to debug / use LogCat.