# Eclipse LogCat - Not Working

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

This is the most frustrating thing ever, LogCat keeps deactivating/disconnecting. After running eclipse, LogCat logs for first run and after that, it goes Blank. I have to restart Eclipse to get it running again, and then same thing happens again. What is matter with it? It used to work fine. I can't recall changes I've made to undo what I (might) have done.

**EDIT** - Screen of Eclipse as requested.

[image]

**EDIT 2** - Screen of currently installed SDK packages

[image]

Comment: How many processes are your running ? Are you running your application project in emulator or device ?

Comment: I am using my Device only.

Comment: have you tried with other devices ? sometimes it's the device that runs crazy

Comment: I've checked my Device, the Developer options seems all normal. I have also restarted the device, but still same problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If the LogCat is empty, the emulator doesn't have the focus. Go to the DDMS perspective and try clicking on the 'emulator' entry in the Devices panel (top-left screen).

Same thing with a device. You just have to click on the entry representing that device and the log messages comes.

Comment: Under Devices in the DDMS perspective, I only see my Phone Device, no emulator

Comment: So check the phone device. In the logcat, you can see your phone too and maybe you have selected a filter that is why your logcat is empty.

Comment: LogCat filter is fine too, Even the "All Messages" is empty.

Comment: Also after hitting "Clear Log", when I run the app again, LogCat stays blank.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your eclipse screen

Comment: See main post above. Added screen of Eclipse.

Comment: What i can say is that you should update your ADT and logcat, then try again. Maybe you are using an older version of logcat because i have never encountered such an issue

Comment: Is it possible I am missing some sdk packages? I uninstalled loads of stuff I didnt think I needed. See EDIT 2 in the main post. Am I missing anything important?

Comment: I would suggest that you re-install your eclipse from scratch and only install API 19 or maybe 14 to 19.

Comment: Okay, will do and post back. Thanks for now

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time [Rahuls method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20828256/1147787) would work, but sometimes even that doesn't work in that case, Kill the ADB and restart the eclipse.

Comment: It happens to me also sometimes, why don't you try to run the deprecated logcat from windows-> preference -> logcat again before closing the logcat, let me know if it works. also try to reconnect your phone through usb again.

Comment: I will try the reinstall ADT suggestion first, and if it comes to it, use deprecated version.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this other post with the same problem will answer this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11967853/241014

Essentially, set the log's buffer to a higher value by going in Eclipse to Window > Preferences > Android > LogCat. Set the "Maximum number of logcat messages to buffer" to something higher than the default of 5,000.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For `Eclipse` **only** when `LogCat` isn't working:

1 - Open Perspective "`DDMS`".
2 - On the left side, click on the device you want to monitor.
3 - Change Perspective back to "`JAVA`".

Comment: How on God's green Earth is a person meant to work that out? Bravo Pedro. This fixed it instantly. `Perspective` is in the `Window` menu @ newbies. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are using cynogenmod in your mobile, try this:

In your device, open "/system/etc/init.d/" folder
If there are many files, try opening each file and find for this line:

**rm /dev/log/main**

Now, comment this line like this: **# rm /dev/log/main**

save the file and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

If you close LogCat and re-open it it will display the information.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question has been asked long before, I am answering for others who might stumble upon this trouble.

In Mars, eclipse 4.5 and linux using GTK 3, if Android Logcat display is missing, add the following in eclipse.ini before "--launcher.appendVmargs".

**--launcher.GTK_version

2**

May also refer these posts.
[Logcat show invisible messages in Eclipse Mars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31403672/logcat-show-invisible-messages-in-eclipse-mars)
[Eclipse GUI broken](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=200053)