# How to view logs of an Android app on Ubuntu?

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

I am working on web services for an Android app, to better understand its working. I want to view the logs of the app on my pc, for this I have done the following things:

1. I have installed Eclipse on my Ubuntu 14.04 pc.
2. I have connected the Android device by using USB cable.
3. I have turned on USB debugging mode on my Android device.

Now my requirement is, I want to view the logs on my PC of the running app on my device. How can I do this?

Comment: have you install usb driver ? if not yet, maybe this [link] (http://www.droidviews.com/setup-adb-usb-drivers-ubuntu-easily/) will be help you

Comment: yes they are installed

Comment: @MohamadDambaPutrabangga no need to install driver on any linux distro

Comment: @Insomania do you mean logs on eclipse like `log.d(?,?);`

Comment: i just want to view the logs of the connected device on my pc

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828207/eclipse-logcat-not-working

Answer (score 0):

If your device is connected and the screen is unlocked, you can view the logs in the `LogCat`, you can open logcat from here:

> Window > Show View > Other > Android > LogCat